# Facebook API get only small images

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i use the facebook api to get my hole facebook-wall.
i work with json:

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_page_id/posts?access_token=$access_token&fields=$fields&limit=$limit";

$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$feed_item_count = count($obj['data']);
```

an i use this in for-loop (for ($x = 0; $x < $feed_item_count; $x++) {)

```
// picture from the link
    $picture = $obj['data'][$x]['picture'];
    $picture_url_arr = explode('&url=', $picture);
    $picture_url = urldecode($picture_url_arr[1]);
```

but i get only a small image but on facebook wall it is a bigger image.
How can i get images with bigger size? Any idea?

Comment: What are the fields in your $fields variable. I think 'full_picture' field will give you the url for the full big picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a way to get larger pictures:

```
/me/posts?fields=full_picture
```